# Send arrays of data from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to send three arrays of data namely `vertexa`, `vertexb` and `edge_id` to HTML page including JavaScript so as to run an algorithm Dijkstra on the vertices. Should I use JSON commands for this?

Comment: take a look at the php function json_encode - you can pass multidimensional associative arrays to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the data, like

```
<?php
$arr=array('cow'=>'black','feet'=>4);
$encoded=json_encode($arr);
```

$encoded is now `{"cow":"black","feet":4}`, which JavaScript can work with. To send this to a page do

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');  
echo $encoded;
```

[header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) has to happen before you output anything to the page, even a space or blank line, or PHP will give an error.

After generating the data as a PHP array, to output it to JS on the initial page load, you can print it out as the following. Not you don't need to output a special header in this case; it's part of your normal text/html document. The header is for an Ajax return.

```
<?php
$json_data=json_encode($your_array);
?>
<script>
   var an_obj=<?php echo $json_data;?>;
</script>
```

Comment: .. .what should be the relevant code for the javascript file ?

Comment: @user522003 It gets a bit complex there, depending - are you using ajax to fetch this data dynamically, or outputting this variable into the page to begin with?

Comment: ... m outputting the variable into the page through javascript .... also m using Ajax to fetch the data Dynamically !

Comment: @user522003 Okay, I've added an example of how to output it into a JS variable. Fetching it with Ajax is a pretty large topic, involving HTML, JS and another PHP file - you may wish to add that as whole new question. Are you using a library such as jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Use `datatype:"json"`   for data and `datatype:"script"` to set the data type for your ajax calls.

On the servers side set content-types to `application/json` and `application/javascript` , respectively.

Comment: What is the difference between application/json and application/javascript , respectively ?

Comment: I have an array in php named as say edge_id[]. Now how should I define the datatype to send to the client i.e. javascript side .

Comment: @user522003 regarding the mime type, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type